# What is the best way to identify what matches the text based on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to know what is the best approach that can indicate for me the best match for text based on list of dictionaries. I have tried using any() but it didn’t work and I even tried to make a normal loop statement that goes through the loop and  if value == text return text but it didn’t work as expected

```
data=[{
"categories":"application update",
"options":["application","update computer application","update computer application","update application computer"],    
},
{
"categories":"computer information",
"options":["computer information","computer information","computer properties"],    
},
{
"categories":"operating system",
"options":["operating system","update computer operating system","computer operating system"],    
},
{
"categories":"adobe software",
"options":["adobe software issue","application adobe issue","fix my adobe application"],    
},
]
```

```
text="computer update"
```

What i managed to do is this bvut it didnt work as expected

```
for i in data:
  for j in i['options']:
    if text== j:
      print(i['categories'])
```

The above data variable include list of dic and im getting text and based on that text i try to best match text with most sutable category
for example text ="update ope4rating system " then catgroies will be only  operating system

for example text="fix adobe software" then catgory will be only adobe software

what im trying to achieve is to determine text will be related to which category . for example update computer will be operating system category and for example adobe software application issue related to adobe software

Thank you

Comment: Why "fix adobe software" will result in "adobe software"? I don't see any option with all 3 words "fix", "adobe", and "software".

Comment: the option exist within the same list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, what you are looking for is partial match, but your code performed exact match (with `==`). Secondly, since you are mentioning `any()` function, my solution will include it:

```py
for datum in data:
    if any("update computer" in option for option in datum["options"]):
        print(datum["categories"])
```

The output:

```
application update
operating system
```

## Update

The original post was not clear that we need to match all the keywords. So here is my revised solution.

```py
def options_match(options, keywords):
    """Return True if at least one option matches all the keywords."""
    keywords = keywords.split()    
    for option in options:
        if all(keyword in option for keyword in keywords):
            return True
    return False

for datum in data:
    if options_match(datum["options"], "computer update"):
        print(datum["categories"])
```

## Second Update

Since the poster wants to locate just one category, not *all*, here is my code revision:

```py
def options_match(options, keywords):
    """Return True if at least one option matches all the keywords."""
    keywords = keywords.split()    
    for option in options:
        if all(keyword in option for keyword in keywords):
            return True
    return False

category = "<NOT FOUND>"
for datum in data:
    if options_match(datum["options"], "computer update"):
        category = datum["categories"]
        break
print(category)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried any() but it didn't work as expected because  if text missing letter it will identify it and some times give me wrong category

Comment: any() function will give me  text contains computer or any other word with same pattern in other categories it will give me all categories

Comment: I just made an update before seeing these comments. To be honest, I don't understand your requirements. If you can update your post with clear, precise requirements, you will get the help you want. I know that English is not the native language for so many people, including myself, but you have to make a clear description in order to get help.

Comment: i need to get only one category, the code outputted 2 categories for me

Comment: Please see my second update

Comment: so far with small data it works fine but i still dont know if code will work i need to try it in a bigger data variable, give mne few min and i will update you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if text == j:
```

to:

```
if text in j:
```

By using == you are requiring your search text to be an exact match of what's in the dictionary and none of your items match exactly but they do start with the search text.

EDIT: Or to find any of your search words in your dictionary strings use:

```
for i in data:
  for j in i['options']:
    if any(word in j for word in text.split(' ')):
      print(i['categories'])
      break
```

Or if you want all keywords to be specified change `any` to `all`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this will not fix it fully for example if  text is "text="computer update"" it will not work

Comment: So, are you looking for those options which contains the word "computer" and the the word "update"?

Comment: Oh you want keywords any way round.  I have updated the answer.  It is important to use the break keyword otherwise you will get duplicate matches.

Comment: @Crapicus, any() function will not work because if text contains computer or any other word with same pattern in other categories it will give me all catgories